# Alternative to OpenCF.FTP - stable

Tags: compact-framework, ftp

I am looking for a STABLE FTP library for Compact Framework. I would prefer a library where I don't have to fix or step through any code, but just use as is.

While the free OpenCf.FTP is great, I think it is at this point creating more work for me than my actual coding and I am afraid I don't have time allotted for this.

Any libs you guys have had experience with? Good/bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Xceed](http://xceed.com) also has a [solid FTP library](http://xceed.com/FTP_NET_CF_Intro.html) for .NET CF.

Comment: is it fast? Currently, it takes 13 seconds to transfer a file that's 5KB. It takes about 16 seconds to login.

My app logs in and retrieves 2 files at startup, so to the user it looks like it takes 40+ seconds to login. If Xceed is similar speed then I will pass. Could you provide some details on your experience with it?

Comment: With the terrible times you are mentioning, I wouldn't be surprised if you had other issues (connectivity problems?) than simply FTP. Xceed FTP should give you faster connection and xfer. Else it's probably not the library's fault.

Comment: Thanks, before purchasing I will certainly test the set-up to eliminate other factors. Currently, the ftp is in passive mode and a majority of download time is actually "sleeping". This seems to be the default mode for OpennetCF.FTP.

Answer (score 3):

Our [Rebex FTP/SSL](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/) supports .NET CF [since 2006](http://www.rebex.net/ftp-ssl.net/history.aspx). It shares the codebase with Rebex FTP which is maintained since 2004. I guess it is probable quite stable - for example Microsoft licensed this FTP/SSL component and is using it in Visual Studio 2010 for web deployment. Source code available.

Comment: Note to 10k users: this does not constitute spam since 1. Martin discloses his relationship with the company openly, and 2. the answer is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [IP*Works from \n Software](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/default.aspx).  Solid and well supported.

Comment: i looked at the site and for the life of me I can't find the trial download for ftp lib for compact framework.

Comment: no idea if they have an eval version.  I had the release from day 1.

Answer (score 1):

What i find the most bizarre about CF is that it lacks FTP functionality. I mean it is a framework for MOBILE apps for God's sake. Perhaps someone from MS could enlighten me on why file transfer functionality is missing from mobile apps framework.

I am sure someone will come with some long and smart sounding explanation. Knock yourself out, it still makes no sense at all.